# How to fix the error about PageRequest in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was working on my project. Then I had an error which I can't handle it.
So my Controller class look like:

```
@Controller
public class CountryController {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepo;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page){
        model.addAttribute("data", countryRepo.
                findAll(new PageRequest(page, 4)));
        return "index";
    }

    public String save(Country c){
        countryRepo.save(c);
    }

}
```

I have an error on `PageRequest` . It says: `.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest @Contract(value = "_,_,null->fail", pure = true) protected PageRequest(int page,int size, @NotNull org.springframework.data.domain.Sort sort`. So I couldn't figure out it. How to fix that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a Sort Object to the PageRequest Constructor. The problem is that your PageRequest constructor is missing a parameter for Sort object

```
new PageRequest(page, 4)
```

Instead you should have something like -

```
new PageRequest(page, 4, Sort.ascending())
```

Comment: Hım,, it gives an error : `Non-static method 'ascending()' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `PageRequest.of(...)` instead of constructor.